# How to fetch details from other website using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, xhtml

I'm trying to make a website which fetches examination results from my university website and shows them on my site.

University site: results.vtu.ac.in/vitavi.php

Someone has already made fastvturesults.com. Can anyone please help me on how it works and provide sample code?

Answer (score 0):

In php you can use simple HTML DOM library for the same which is available at [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)

// Create DOM from URL or file

```
    $html = file_get_html('the website url whos data you want');
```

// Find all images ang get src attribute value

```
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
        echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

// Find all links and get href attribute

```
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
        echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use cURL which you may need to first enable (or even outright install a copy of the HTTP server software if it wasn't compiled with it).

Once you've enabled cURL and the function doesn't trigger an error it will fetch anything you tell it to.

Time to start reading tutorials and *then* asking *much more specific questions*:

https://davidwalsh.name/curl-download